# How to process Entities into Spring which originate from an external jar file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hello I am have a project with the general following structure:

1. Core Spring Application, which has an API integrated into it.
2. Plugins, which are built based on the API.

The Plugins are compiled independently and stored in a folder named "plugins", which is generated in the directory in which the Core Application runs.

The Plugins contain `@Entity` classes which extend a Super Class from the API.

The Core Spring Application can successfully read and load any classes from the plugins, when loaded independently from Spring. (I have written my own ClassLoader and ClassLoaderManager)

**My issue:** I have to load the `@Entity` classes from the Plugins into Spring, so that it recognizes the `@Entity` classes as "Managed Types".

**Failed Solution:**
I have attempted to remedy this problem by using this Bean:

```java
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setPackagesToScan(// I inject the packages here);
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    CustomUnitPostProcessor postProcessor = new CustomPostProcessor("base package");
    bean.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(postProcessor);
    return bean;
}

public class CustomUnitPostProcessor extends ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

    public CustomUnitPostProcessor(String basePackage) {
        super(basePackage);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui) {
        // Adding Jar File Package URLs to PUI via pui.addJarFileURL();
        super.postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(pui);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this method fails due to the `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [// Class which is supposed to be loaded]`. Which breaks the `EntityManagerFactory`.

I am open to any solutions which would either fix my failed solution, or would achieve the same result.

-AwesomeDude091

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your class loader. Have you configured the application, including Hibernate, to use it?

Comment: I have configured the application, but how would I set the ClassLoaderService of Hibernate through Spring @AndyWilkinson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was based upon my failed solution and involved injecting a custom Class Loader Service into hibernate. Link for complete answer: [How do I inject Hibernate ClassLoaderService into Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160078/how-do-i-inject-hibernate-classloaderservice-into-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

> I have to load the `@Entity` classes from the Plugins into Spring, so that it recognizes the `@Entity` classes as "Managed Types".

When entities are in in the classpath of underlying spring-boot application (assuming in `package com.example.plugin;`), then it comes down to annotate your application/configuration with:

```
@EntityScan({"com.example.plugin" /*, ... */})
```

... to "manage" them in terms of JPA.

When we also want to load ([spring-data](/questions/tagged/spring-data)) "jpa repositories", then (also/alternatively(?)):

```
@EnableJpaRepositories({"package.of.repository"/*, ...*/})
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html