# How do I inject Hibernate ClassLoaderService into Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi I need to pass my own `ClassLoaderServiceImpl` into Hibernate. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to pass it into Hibernate over Spring Boot. How would I do it?

Here is what I got:

```
ClassLoaderServiceImpl serviceImpl = new ClassLoaderServiceImpl(customClassLoader);
// Magical code that injects serviceImpl into Spring Boot, which will give it to Hibernate
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be tricky.

1. you need to use specific [EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl constructor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/boot/internal/EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java#L192) to inject your own implementation of `ClassLoaderServiceImpl`
2. `spring-orm` uses another constructor which does not fit your needs: [SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java#L52) - thus, you need to override/inherit SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider
3. next you need to override [HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#getPersistenceProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java#L119)
4. after that you will need to override boot auto-configurations.

Comment: Say Hibernate is now refusing to generate your database tables... Could this be because of this? @AndreyB.Panfilov